# Keyboard shortcuts don't work at https://stackexchange.com/, or in the network profile

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, keyboard-shortcuts

Over at https://stackexchange.com/, or in my network profile, none of the keyboard shortcuts take any effect on the site.  Clicking <kbd>S</kbd> does not open the search; clicking <kbd>I</kbd> doesn't open the global inbox, clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> doesn't open the help list, and the same holds true for the Achievements Icon and everything else, AFAIK.  Can we fix this, please?